# Allow edits which have already started even when queue is full

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

**Note:** this question is *not* about why the edit queue is frequently full.

---

In the last few days it's happened a few times that I clicked "edit" on a question, put maybe 5 minutes into significantly improving a question, and pressed "submit", only to get the message:

> The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!

But 'a few minutes' were never enough for the edit queue to get smaller again, so that in each case I ended up leaving the page and losing my edit. Which is quite frustrating!

I understand that sometimes, the edit queue just gets too full, and a limit is required to prevent the queue from getting longer and longer over time. I therefore always have understanding when the same message appears **before** starting the edit, to keep me from starting at all and wasting my time. However, displaying the message after someone has already put significant effort into the edit will only remove motivation to edit at all, or encourage people to edit more hastily.

There are a few ways that this could be improved:

1. Allow edits which have already started to be submitted, even if the queue is full. The limit on the queue is not there for technical reasons, so this should be possible. Surely the number of edits in progress at one time is very limited anyway, so this would not cause the queue to fill up massively? Or if this is a problem, maybe the limit on the queue needs to kick in a bit earlier.
2. Don't add edits to the queue when it is full, but still offer them to the person who wrote the original post. Many edits don't need to be approved through the queue at all, so why should this method of approval be blocked by a full queue?
3. At least make the message appear as a popup or banner while the person is editing, and not only upon pressing `submit`. This should be possible to implement, as a similar thing already happens when two edits are done simultaneously.

Comment: Or just earn 76 more rep.

Comment: @SamuelLiew That is certainly the easiest solution for me personally! But the question also applies to many users with <2k rep, and those who may never reach this privilege due to a lack of technical ability to write answers, yet still want to contribute to the site and know how to improve a post.

Comment: No, it *is* the solution  - the full phrase that @SamuelLiew could have said is "just earn 86 more rep and start reviewing those edits so queue is never full". :)

Comment: It's not the solution, it's a workaround.

Comment: It really is a workaround, if you are a new user to stack and you just wanted to fix something, for example.

Comment: The fix for this has been done, just needs to make its way into production in the next day or so. Will update when ready. The queue will still have a limit, but if you are brought to the edit menu, you will be allowed to submit your suggested edit for that specific post.

Comment: More generally it would be nice to have some kind of lock mechanism for edits. It's incredibly frustrating when I'm trying to make an edit and someone else completes a different edit in the interim. If I don't check the other edit, I risk my own edit being rejected, or scrubbing changes that I should also have incorporated. If I try to check it, I risk losing track of my own unsaved work, plus I still have the task of evaluating that edit to see whether I should keep anything from it. And while I'm trying to figure that out, a third person could have started making more changes....

Comment: Re *"losing my edit"*: You can always save it off-line (three items, title, body, and summary) and submit it later. (Though, is it required to do it "preemptively" (as a backup, before submitting)?). Yes, it is a bit cumbersome, but doable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The change is now live on the site for this fix, so regardless of a full review queue, if you had access to the edit menu, your edit will go through.

**Update February 22, 2023**: We've rolled this back due to an error reported in [Full edit queue blocking edits on own post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423311/1366033).  Will update this post when fixed and re-deployed.

**Update March 2, 2023**: The error previously reported has been fixed and is on production. Initially we added a new permission for a user who is shown the edit menu, to be allowed to submit their edit regardless if the review queue is full, so their work isn't lost. This unintentionally caused a side effect where users with privilege couldn't edit a wiki post or edit their own post. This should be back to working now along with the original solution to let users submit their edits.

Comment: On March 17, during the review process of first question, I try to edit a question.. unable to save because the queue was full. Can you disable the edit button if the edit queue is full (in the review taks and the website) ?

Comment: Possible unintended consequence? [Able to suggest edits despite being edit banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387963/able-to-suggest-edits-despite-being-edit-banned)