Moderation edit queue warning can cause inefficiency
Currently, when reviewing a post which requires a complex / significant edit, a great deal of time might be spent by the reviewer implementing the necessary edits to the post. If the edit queue is subsequently full, the reviewer will not be made aware of this until she attempts to submit the edit and any associated comments.
The warning will be displayed as follows:

'The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!".

This UI flow seems inefficient as the reviewer is unaware until attempting to submit. This could cause a number of outcomes including but not limited to:

The reviewer abandoning the edit altogether due to time constraints despite having contributed significant edits to the post
The reviewer having to attempt multiple subsequent submission attempts at arbitrary times causing inefficient server load

I suspect there is a better way we could go about the messaging here (albeit the technological implications would have to be considered). For example:

Some realistic representation of the length of the queue or the approximate time until the queue is likely to have capacity at current rates ('please wait a few minutes' seems lazy).
A warning before or during the edit so as to make the reviewer aware that the queue is full. (A reviewer may then choose to skip the review due to time constraints).
Expanding the queue capacity so as to decrease the probability that this will occur

I understand some of the main objections and would be interested to hear yours also.
I'd be open to suggestions. Clearly, the queue needs to be of finite length; however, can we do better with either the messaging; the mechanism or both?

related: 1) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416102/why-doesnt-so-block-the-edit-option-if-the-edit-queue-is-already-full-and-why-c 2) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350377/reviewing-while-edit-queue-full 3) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346065/preventing-suggested-edit-queue-being-frequently-full probably many more

With the preface that I very much agree with you that this is a problem and something really ought to be done... Proposed solution 1 is probably infeasible, due to both other editors submitting new edits potentially the moment the queue gets capacity, and the likely  unpredictable rate at which edits are reviewed.  Proposed solution 3 won't work because the issue is the rate at which edits are reviewed; the queue never gets anywhere near empty.  A longer queue would just increase the time that it takes for the edits that do get submitted to be approved.

When outside of review, the system already checks whether the queue is full before allowing an edit suggestion when the "edit" button is pushed. It shouldn't be super difficult to force that same check for lower-rep users in the review queues available to users without full edit privileges. Given that, I'd probably call this a bug rather than a FR since the feature exists, it's just not implemented in review as it should be. As a note, should this be implemented, they should be certain to include the feature allowing suggestions to be completed even if the queue fills in the interim.

For reference - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398145/allow-edits-which-have-already-started-even-when-queue-is-full/423305#423305

Related, more recently: Should the review be skipped automatically if one wants to edit but the queue is full and the reviewer does not have full-edit privileges?
